# How to incrementally count the number of repeated instances

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, window-functions, mysql-5.6

I want to incrementally count the number of repeated instances in a table, so if I have a table like this:

```
id   | name  | status |
-----------------------
1    | John  |    1   | 
2    | Jane  |    1   |
4    | John  |    1   |
5    | John  |    1   |
6    | Jane  |    1   |
7    | John  |    1   |
```

Using the column "name" as reference, the output would be

```
id   | name  | status | count |
------------------------------
1    | John  |    1   |   1   |
2    | Jane  |    1   |   1   |
4    | John  |    1   |   2   |
5    | John  |    1   |   3   |
6    | Jane  |    1   |   2   |
7    | John  |    1   |   4   |
```

The DBMS implementation is MySQL, version 5.6

Comment: *The DBMS implementation is MySQL* Not enough. Version?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I'm using MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 5.x, where window functions are not available, one option uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
    (
        select count(*)
        from mytable t1
        where t1.name = t.name and t1.id <= t.id
    ) rn
from mytable t
```

You could also do this with user variables:

```
select t.*,
    case when @name = (@name := name)
        then @rn := @rn + 1
        else @rn := 1
    end as rn
from (select * from mytable order by name, id) t
cross join (select @name := null, @rn := 0) x
```

There are pros and cons to both approaches. The second solution scales better than the first against a large dataset, however user variables are tricky in MySQL, and are now officially planned for deprecation in a future version.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as count
from t
order by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.status, COUNT(*) `count`
FROM tablename t1
JOIN tablename t2 USING (name)
WHERE t1.id >= t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name, t1.status
ORDER BY t1.id
```